# How did Gauss and Lagrange derive Gauss law of Electrostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss

On Wikipedia, these two pages are mentioned :[Lagrange](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=4XkAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA619&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) and [Gauss](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=0TxeAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false)
however I am an English speaker and can not comprehend any of the one, can someone provide the translated pages or shortly their line of reasoning?

Comment: Please fix typos.

Comment: could you pease point out?